# Sum rows (or columns) of a 2d matrix into a 1d array in an Excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there any way to tell specify to Excel that it should perform a per-row calculation within a 2d matrix? For instance, if I have an array defined

```
{1,0,0;0,0,1;1,0,1}
```

i.e.

```
1 0 0
0 0 1
1 0 1
```

Is there a formula that can allow me to operate on the array `{1;1;2}`?

The eventual goal in this would most likely to be to further transform *that* array using an expression such as `{1;1;2}>=2` or `MATCH(2,{1;1;2},0)`, but the important thing isn't so much what the outer expression is as *that* the transformation takes place at all.

Of course, much of this can in many cases be outsourced to operations on a helper column, but there are numerous times when solving a problem with space feels like an inelegant approach.

Comment: If you place your data in a Table, you can perform calculations on the individual rows and columns of that Table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[MMULT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/mmult-function-40593ed7-a3cd-4b6b-b9a3-e4ad3c7245eb) would do what you wants.

```
{=MMULT({1,0,0;0,0,1;1,0,1},{1;1;1})}
```

used as array formula (CSE) results in `{1;1;2}`.

```
1,0,0       1       1*1+0*1+0*1  =  1
0,0,1   x   1   =   0*1+0*1+1*1  =  1
1,0,1       1       1*1+0*1+1*1  =  2
```

When `MMULT` is wrapped in other functions which take their parameters as arrays, there may not be the need for pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter. For example

```
=MATCH(2,MMULT({1,0,0;0,0,1;1,0,1},{1;1;1}),0)
```

results in `3` without entering the formula using Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Comment: No need for CSE.

Comment: @XOR LX: How? `=MMULT({1,0,0;0,0,1;1,0,1},{1;1;1})` results in `1` only and not in an array. Of course wrapped in other functions there **may** not be the need for CSE.

Comment: Of course. But on its own it certainly doesn't produce an array in-cell, with or without CSE! Unless of course you meant a MULTI-CELL array formula?

Comment: @XOR LX: "Unless of course you meant a MULTI-CELL array formula?": Of course. What else a `MMULT` not wrapped in another function should be used for?

Comment: To you that's obvious, but perhaps not to the OP nor any other people viewing this thread. Perhaps make explicit within the post?

Comment: Actually, you really don't need CSE - but to avoid it for my purposes you need to use the index trick, i.e. INDEX(MMULT({1,0,0;0,0,1;1,0,1},{1;1;1}),,).

Comment: Worth further noting that it looks like the source array needs transposing first - the result of just using MMULT is {2,0,2} rather than {1;1;2} because it is summing columns into a row rather than rows into a column!

Comment: @tobriand: I cannot reproducing the need for transposing. For me `{=MMULT({1,0,0;0,0,1;1,0,1},{1;1;1})}` results in `{1;1;2}`. Test using `VBA`: `Range("A1:A3").FormulaArray = "=MMULT({1,0,0;0,0,1;1,0,1},{1;1;1})"` having an empty sheet as the active sheet.

Comment: Yep, you're right - I must have had rows and columns mixed up in my source data. Still had to use transpose to make it work for me, but not because the formula is working differently.